# Better way to write this composed value

Tags: javascript

I have this code.:

```
const OnLoadStatisticsTypes = loadOnMount('statisticsTypes', fetchStatisticsTypes, 'root')(StatisticBalloons)

export default loadOnMount('appsStatistics', fetchAppsStatistics, 'root')(OnLoadStatisticsTypes)
```

But i don't know how to do better. I tried.:

```
export default compose(
  loadOnMount('appsStatistics', fetchAppsStatistics, 'root'),
  loadOnMount('statisticsTypes', fetchStatisticsTypes, 'root'),
  StatisticBalloons
)
```

But not works too.

How can i improve this script?

Comment: This method loadOnMount returns a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this `compose` function from Redux?

```js
export default compose(
  loadOnMount('appsStatistics', fetchAppsStatistics, 'root'),
  loadOnMount('statisticsTypes', fetchStatisticsTypes, 'root')
)(StatisticBalloons)
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks! I forgot to use curry

Answer (score 0):

If you write this method returning a promise, them you can compose all using `Promise.all`. See the example:

```
const loadOnMount = (param1, param2, param3) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //Your logical here
    })
}
```

Then you can compose like this:

```
Promise.all([
  loadOnMount('appsStatistics', fetchAppsStatistics, 'root'),
  loadOnMount('appsStatistics2', fetchAppsStatistics, 'root'),
  loadOnMount('appsStatistics3', fetchAppsStatistics, 'root')
])
.then(function(result){
  //Handle the array with all resolved promises
})
```

Comment: In this case I need get the value from the previous function.